Некорректное отображение текстуры по краям в Unreal Engine
Я создал новую текстуру 64 на 64 и наложил её на простой куб, но она отображается некорректно.
Вот текстура:

Вот так, почему-то, выглядит куб с этой текстурой:

Объясните пожалуйста, почему такое происходит, и как это исправить?
P.S. Сталкивался с этой проблемой не только в UE, но и в Unity.

В свойствах текстуры поиграйте с X-axis Tiling Method  и Y-axis Tiling Method. Ваша текстура наложена с повторением. При этом билинейная фильтрация (сглаживание) текстуры подсасывает пиксели с противоположного края квадрата.

Да, это сработало. Спасибо!

Для того, чтобы решить данную проблему, нужно было во вкладке Свойства текстуры (двойной щелчок ЛКМ по текстуре) изменить значения параметров X-axis Tiling Method и Y-axis Tiling Method с Wrap на Clamp.
